# Check if an NSString contains a valid number but localized

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

How to check if a string contains a valid number considering localized number formats.

This question is not primary about converting a number. I can do that with NSNumberFormatter. And if I can't then I don't even need to do it and can leave the string as string. But I need to check whether it contains a valid numer.

BTW, we are in the middle of a textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange: ... delegate method. Here I want to prevent keying in illegal characters by returning NO.

This is the code that I have:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Only test for numbers if it is a certain text field. 
    if (textField == self.numValueTextField) {
        NSString *resultingString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];

        // The user deleting all input is perfectly acceptable.
        if ([resultingString length] == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        double holder;

        NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString: resultingString];

        BOOL isNumeric = [scan scanDouble: &holder] && [scan isAtEnd];

        if (isNumeric) {

            [self.detailItem setValue:number forKey:kValueDouble];
        }

        return isNumeric;
    }
    return YES;  // default for any other text field - if any.
}
```

That works fine but it implies English notations. Meaning the floating point must be a pont. But it could be a comma or whatever in certain parts of the world.

I do know how to check for certain characters. So I could check for 0-9, comma and point. But is there a 'proper' way of doing that?

If it is of importance: I am in an iOS environment.

Answer (score 8):

A number formatter will use the current locale's information by default, so it should be able to do this checking for you. Just try to format the string. If the result is `nil`, then it's not valid.

```
static NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
//... build string
NSNumber * num = [formatter numberFromString:resultingString];
BOOL isNumeric = (num != nil);
```

For example:

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];

// US uses period as decimal separator
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"3.1415"]);   // Valid NSNumber
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"3.14.15"]);  // nil
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"31415"]);    // Valid
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"3,1415"]);   // nil

// Italy uses a comma as decimal separator
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"it"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"3.1415"]);    // nil
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"3.14.15"]);   // nil
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"31415"]);     // Valid
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"3,1415"]);    // Valid
```

Or you might prefer to use `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:`, which will simply return `YES` or `NO` to indicate success at parsing, and also give you an error object if you're interested in further details.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. It is not documented that it returns nil upon "illegal" formats.

Comment: Huh, I thought it was. Well, you could also use `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` which explicitly returns `NO` if it can't parse the input. Pretty sure `numberFromString:` is a wrapper around that.

Comment: You will need some special cases for "", which you always want to be legal (it means the user is deleting) and an initial "." which may be legal, but will not format as a number. You also need to build the test string correctly, replacing the characters passed to you (don't forget to test pasting more than a single character). It's not that hard, but these were the reasons I went with testing the input directly.

Comment: Thanks. That is considered already. See my code. I was just looking for a good automatically localized replacement for the `isNumeric=...` statement. I have implemented it so far and will do some test this evening.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it. The key piece of information you want is `[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]`, which will tell you the current decimal separator. Then you look for any characters that aren't in the legal set.

```
- (BOOL)isLegalDigitString:(NSString *)string
              forTextField:(UITextField *)textField
           hasDecimalPoint:(BOOL)hasDecimalPoint
{
  // It's always legal to delete
  if ([string length] == 0)
  {
    return YES;
  }

  // Only legal characters
  NSString *decimalSeparator = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];

  NSString *legalCharacters = [@"1234567890" stringByAppendingString:
                               (hasDecimalPoint ? decimalSeparator
                                : @"")];
  NSCharacterSet *forbiddenCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:legalCharacters] invertedSet];
  if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:forbiddenCharacterSet].location != NSNotFound)
  {
    return NO;
  }

  // Only one decimal point
  if (hasDecimalPoint &&
      [string rangeOfString:decimalSeparator].location != NSNotFound &&
      [[textField text] rangeOfString:decimalSeparator].location != NSNotFound)
  {
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

As an example of how I use this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  if (textField == [self integerTextField])
  {
    return [self isLegalDigitString:string forTextField:textField hasDecimalPoint:NO];
  }
  else if (textField == [self floatTextField])
  {
    return [self isLegalDigitString:string forTextField:textField hasDecimalPoint:YES];
  }

  return YES;
}
```

The one thing this doesn't do really well is manage limited precision (a field that can only have tenths for instance). It would need some redesign for that.

Comment: Thanks. Looks good to me. Just one question. Why do you pass into the method the text field and the string separately? Woudn't one of them be enough to do the job?

Comment: The string is the suggested change, not the string that's already in there. I pass the text field because I want to check the current value for already-existing decimal separators (so the user can't type two of them).

Comment: Thanks, yes, it took me a while tonight to figure that. As it is the suggested change it must not be part of the text field's text. It will only be added to the text field's property when YES is returned.

Comment: This is the simplest solution which will work 90% of cases. Why only 90%? Because not all the languages use arabic numerals. `NSNumberFormatter` is safer to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSLocale to get the localized grouping separator and then strip it out of your strings since NSScanner doesn't handle grouping.

```
NSString *sep = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator];
NSString *string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:sep withString:@""];
```

Initialize an NSScanner that takes into account localized decimal separators.

```
NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:string2];
```

Then proceed with your NSScanner code as it is. Using NSScanner is more robust than the hand coded methods because it handles all IEEE compliant numbers including +/- and scientific notation. It's also shorter.

Comment: Any input that allows the input of grouping separators is bad. Grouping separators should be added by the app, not by the user. Always.

Comment: Agree. The code is about evaluating strings as numbers, not about how those strings got there. If grouping separators are present, they get stripped out. If not, no harm. I think it's more complete and generalized this way, but you can remove that part if it's not applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, any test for valid numbers that should work even for partial numbers is very tricky to implement.

1. Don't try to reimplement the checks already implemented in `NSNumberFormatter`. Different languages use different decimal separators but also different numerals (EDIT: unfortunately, `NSNumberFormatter` cannot validate non-arabic numerals either).
2. There are many special cases which are not valid numbers but which can become valid numbers, e.g. an empty string, a minus sign, a decimal separator, a minus sign combined with a decimal separator. If you allow scientific notation, it will get much more complicated.

The simplest solution is to check only the final number. Check the input when the user confirms (taps enter, taps outside the input view).

However, also note that `NSNumberFromatter` can actually validate partial strings. See its superclass `NSFormatter` for more info.

Comment: This, unfortunately, creates a horrible user experience. Now that they've entered an invalid number and tapped enter, what do you do? Show an alert? It's far better to prevent errors in the first place than to force the user to fix them later. Supporting non-Arabic numerals is a commitment that requires testing. Accepting non-Arabic numerals in your text fields, but not actually testing that it works end-to-end makes a bad experience for everyone. It's better to explicitly not support it than to just fail to test it, or create bad user experience in its pursuit.

Comment: @RobNapier No, alert is always a bad idea but there are many other possibilities - for example: selecting the first character that is invalid (to bring it to attention), adding a red border around the input, etc. Prevention using `shouldChangeCharacters` isn't perfect from UI perspective either. You press a button and nothing happens. Copy-pasting a number with bad characters (e.g. bad decimal point) doesn't work and the user doesn't know why. When we were implementing something similar, our designers decided to create our own keyboard to prevent the users to enter invalid numbers.

Comment: This is a good exploration of the challenges, and how you sometimes must create much more complicated things, like a dedicated keyboard, if you want to create a good solution. `NSNumberFormatter` by itself is a long way from a full answer, and unfortunately gives the impression that "now it's international" when you haven't tested for that. It's worth noting that when you put iOS into Arabic, you don't get the numerals that Arabic speakers commonly use (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠). You still get the "Arabic" (not actually used by Arabic speakers...) numerals. This is a hint from Apple, about the challenge.